# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Trying to get data from collection to return email fails

Tags: node.js, rest, nodemailer

I am getting this Error

> 

```
PS D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend> npm start
> 
> > onepercentcrm@1.0.0 start D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend
> > node app.js
> 
> Listening on port 5000 Connected to DB (node:29312)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: UsersAdminList
> validation failed: admin_email: Cast to string failed for value "[   {
>     _id: new ObjectId("61a89e4fbd7d1bc03825d3bd"),
>     superadmin_name: 'Sam Holland',
>     superadmin_email: '*********@hotmail.com',
>     __v: 0,
>     superadmin_pass: '$2b$10$O3TKhwEQA9YpTYA8DsbyfO/hXwdzxAXQ7.rwvz/XcvqJ1WMoWn/Ii'   } ]"
> (type Array) at path "admin_email"
>     at model.Document.invalidate (D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2869:32)
>     at model.$set (D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1420:12)
>     at model.$set (D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1122:16)
>     at model.Document (D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:150:12)
>     at new model (D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4746:15)
>     at RegisterAdminUser (file:///D:/node_apps/Backend-node_backend/controller/AdminUserListController/AdminUserListController.js:58:21)
> 
>     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) (Use `node --trace-warnings
> ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:29312)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id:  1) (node:29312) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning:
> Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise
> rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process
> with a non-zero exit code. Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y PS
> D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend>
```

Now i am trying to do something, To get the Admin Email so i can use Nodemailer to send automatic Emails as the case maybe. So the REST api is supposed to get email from a collection (table) `SuperAdminListModel.find` and then send email to the admin and the end user.

My source code is looking like this

```
import AdminListModel from "../../model/AdminUserList/AdminUserList.js";
import SuperAdminListModel from "../../model/SuperAdminModel/SuperAdminModel.js";
import services from "../../utils/services.js";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";


const dispatch_emails =(admin_email, email, fullname, company_name) =>{
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: '587',
        auth: {
            user: '*************@gmail.com',
            pass: '************'
        },
        secureConnection: 'false',
        tls: {
            ciphers: 'SSLv3',
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: '*********@gmail.com',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Account Registration Successful!',
        html: '<h3>Attention,' + fullname + ' , </h3><p><h3>Your Account has been successfully setup.</h3></p><p> Please allow a maximum of 24 - 48 Hours for Review and succesful setup and approval of your online account.</p></br>Regards,</br> Online Services.'
    };

    const AdminNotifyEmail = {
        from: '************@gmail.com',
        to: admin_email,
        subject: 'Account Registration for ' + email + ', with Fullname : ' + fullname + ' (' + company_name + ')',
        html: '<h3>Attention Admin , </h3><p>A new User has registered his Access with the following Information: </br> <strong>Username : ' + email + '</strong></br><strong>Company Name : ' + company_name + '</strong></br><strong>Date of Registration: ' + (new Date()).toLocaleString() + '</strong></br>Regards</br>Online Services.</p>'
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.send({ error: false, data: info, message: 'OK' });
    })

    transporter.sendMail(AdminNotifyEmail, function (error, info) {
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.send({ error: false, data: info, message: 'OK' });
    })
}

export const RegisterAdminUser = async (req, res) => {
    const superadmin_email = await SuperAdminListModel.find({});
    const existingUser = await AdminListModel.findOne({
        $or: [{ email: req.body.email }],
    });
    if (existingUser) {
        return res.status(409).json({ errors: { email: "User already exists" } });
    }
    const newUser = new AdminListModel({
        admin_email : superadmin_email,
        company_name: req.body.company_name,
        fullname: req.body.fullname,
        email: req.body.email,
        phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
        timezone: req.body.timezone
    });

    const payload1 = {
        _id: newUser._id,
    };

    await newUser.save()
    const token = jwt.sign(payload1, services.JWT_KEY, {
        expiresIn: 31556926,
    });

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        if (err) {
            // console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
        }
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, async (err, hash) => {
            if (err) {
                // console.log("err: ", err);
                return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
            }
            newUser.password = hash;
            await newUser.save();
            dispatch_emails(admin_email, newUser.email, newUser.fullname, newUser.company_name);
            const payload = {
                _id: newUser._id,
                email: req.body.email,
            };
            const token = jwt.sign(payload, services.JWT_KEY, {
                expiresIn: 31556926,
            });
        })
        return res.status(200).json({
            message: "User registered Successfully",
            token: token,
            user: newUser,
        });
    })
};


export const listUsers = async (req, res) => {
    /*const userId = req.query.userId || req.user._id;
    // console.log(userId);
    const currentUser = await SuperAdminListModel.findById(userId);

    if (!currentUser) {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: "User not found" });
    }

    */
    AdminListModel.find({}).exec(function (err, users) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
        } else {
            res.json({ message: 'OK', data: users })
        }
    })
};
```

**Edits**

My schemas for both of them Looks thus

```
import Mongoose from "mongoose";

const AdminUserListSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    admin_email :{
        type:String,
    },
    company_name :{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        required:true
    },
    fullname :{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        unique:true,
        lowercase:true,
        trim:true,
        required:true
    },
    phone_number :{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        required:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String
    },
    timezone:{
        type:String,

    },
    created:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const AdminListModel = Mongoose.model('UsersAdminList', AdminUserListSchema);
export default AdminListModel;
```

Comment: Can you post your `AdminListModel` schema definition?

Comment: @LucaPizzini pls see Edits

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing a JSON array to the `admin_email` field, which is of type `string`.
Querying with `find({})` will return a list of objects.

You should either:

1. Filter the `SuperAdminListModel` with `findOne` to return a single object and assign the `superadmin_email` to the property if the object is not empty

```
  const superadminUser = await SuperAdminListModel.findOne({ // Filter by some condition });
  const newUser = new AdminListModel({
    admin_email: superadminUser ? superadminUser.superadmin_email : '',
    ...
  });
```

2. Filter the result of the `find({})` query to retrieve a single object and assign its `superadmin_email` to `admin_email`

```
  const superadminList = await SuperAdminListModel.find({});
  const superadminUser = superadminList.find(admin => // Filter by some condition)
  const newUser = new AdminListModel({
    admin_email: superadminUser ? superadminUser.superadmin_email : '',
    ...
  });
```